# Regex Validation in Model Driven PowerApps

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, powerapps-modeldriven

I am trying to validate a field in my model driven app form using regex.
But so far I am unable to find any resource regarding that.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Out-of-Box support for regex validations. But you can do it using JavaScript web resource on change of that attribute from entity form.

[Apply business logic using client scripting in model-driven apps using JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/client-scripting)